# Is there any other input file type for LibSVM other than text file?

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

Is there any other input file type for `LibSVM` other than text file? If I try to save my data from MATLAB in a text file, it creates a 2 GB file, I want to use **`libsvmread`** to read the data from a matrix file or another file types to save time.

Comment: Just use the Matlab interface to libsvm. See the docs.

Comment: Hello Donda, many thanks for your reply. I tried it, but could not figure out the right way. My question is, do I need to format the data as <index>:<value> <index>:<value>? If yes, I have a char array called 'aa' with the format '1 1:3 2:0 3:8; 3 1:5 2:0 3:8; 4 1:5 2:7 3:9'. Please be kind to show me the code for the libsvmread

Comment: I'm sorry, I never used the text file interface. But I can assure you that the Matlab interface works perfectly. Btw., why is your data file so large? How many features and data points do you have?

Comment: It is from a simulation run which has per second data for two hours. also i want to classify the data in 6 classes